# Somers' D for continous variables

Tags: somers-d

I have read up Somers' D and everywhere it states that the statistic is a measure of association between ordinal variables. Can someone explain to me why I cannot use this metric for assessing the relationship between an ordinal or binary dependent variable and a continuous independent variable? Assuming I have a finite sample, it should always be mathematically possible to assign ranks to a continuous variable and calculate Somers' D. In other words, is Somers' D still applicable, if my dependent variable continuous?

Comment: continuous variables are ordinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use Somers' D if one or even both variables are continuous.

The only requirement is that values can be compared within variable.

Depending on which of the two variables is continuous, D will correspond to Kendall's tau.